# Prism for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

I have used Prism MVVM in Xamarin.Forms for a few weeks now, and went through its documentation as well. I know I might have just scratched the surface. However, is it safe to say that what it offers is essentially a different approach to Navigation (and maybe dependency injection)? I miss to see more to it, and would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

from the [docs](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/index.html)

> Prism provides an implementation of a collection of design patterns
>   that are helpful in writing well-structured and maintainable XAML
>   applications, including MVVM, dependency injection, commands,
>   EventAggregator, and others.

Comment: Well, if it was only about the definition, I would not have asked. My question is about the practical point of view from the developer's perspective. When it comes to hands-on experience. The keyword in my question is "essentially." I am not talking about the ancillary features such as commanding and others. I really am under the impression that Prism (and maybe all the other Xamarin.Forms MVVM frameworks) is "centrally" about navigation.